# How to pass props of TouchableOpacity to parent component in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have made a child component which has `TouchableOpacity`, I want to pass props of `TouchableOpacity` like `disabled` to parent component

child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps} from 'react-native';

export interface ComponentProps {
    touchProps?: TouchableOpacityProps;
}

const ListComponent = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    const touchProps = props.touchProps || {};

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            {...touchProps}>
        {/* other things */}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Here I have declared `touchProps`, I want to use this in parent component

parent component:

```
<ListComponent 
    touchProps={disabled={true}}
/>
```

I am getting error:

`Type '{ true: any; }' has no properties in common with type 'TouchableOpacityProps'.`

I am not able to find what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `touchProps` as an `object` like so:

```js
<ListComponent 
    touchProps={{ disabled: true }}
/>
```

Comment: @pratteekshaurya please mark as accepted to close the question